# What Inning is it?

Tags: code-golf

## Goal

In light of the World Series being around the corner, I need a program that can read the box scores and tell me what inning it is. This is complicated slightly because baseball uses an odd method to record the score. They don't write down the at-bat team's score for the inning until they've scored a run (and are still going) or have finished their at-bat. Thus a 0 on the scoreboard always means a finished at-bat. For example:

```
Example A:
Inning| 1| 2| 3| 4| 5| 6| 7| 8| 9|
  Them| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 2|  |  |  |
    Us| 0| 0| 2| 0| 0| 0|  |  |  |

Example B:
Inning| 1| 2| 3| 4| 5| 6| 7| 8| 9|
  Them| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 2|  |  |  |
    Us| 0| 0| 2| 0| 0| 1|  |  |  |

Example C:
Inning| 1| 2| 3| 4| 5| 6| 7| 8| 9|
  Them| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 2|  |  |  |
    Us| 0| 0| 2| 0| 0|  |  |  |  |

#Them is the Away Team, Us is the Home Team (who are the guys you root for)
```

- Example A: We know we're at the top of the 7th because Us has a recorded 0 in the Bottom of the 6th and the Top of the 7th is blank.
- Example B: It can either be the Bottom of the 6th or the Top of the 7th.
- Example C: It can either be the Top or Bottom of the 6th.

Your task is to return which inning(s) it could be.

## Input

Two lists of non-negative integers. Lists will be assumed jagged with the Away team's list being either the same size or one element larger in comparison to the Home team's. You can take the scores in either order but state in your answer if you do not use the default. I.e., Away Team then Home team (the default), or Home team then Away team (reversed). They can also be padded with dummy data if you want, state in your answer if you do so.

## Output

A string or something equivalent which identifies the inning number and whether it's the top or bottom. E.g. `7B 8T`, `B7 T8`, `['7B','8T']` are all fine. If there are two answers, you must output both. The format is pretty flexible though.

## Rules

- Input will always be valid
- Games can go into indefinite extra innings. Your program should be able to support up to 255 innings.
- Standard Loopholes are forbidden
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code wins

## Test Cases

```
#Input:
[[], 
 []] 
#Output: 1T

#Input:
[[0], 
 []] 
#Output: 1B

#Input:
[[0,0,0,1], 
 [0,0,0,0]] 
#Output: 5T

#Input:
[[0,0,0,1], 
 [0,0,0,1]] 
#Output: 4B, 5T

#Input:
[[0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1],
 [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1]] 
#Output: 10B, 11T

#Input:
[[0,0,0,1], 
 [0,0,0]] 
#Output: 4T, 4B

#Input:
[[0,0,0,0], 
 [0,0,0]] 
#Output: 4B
```

Comment: Can we take the two lists in reverse order? i.e. bottom then top?

Comment: @JoKing Sure, as long as it's noted and the answer still matches up correctly.

Comment: Is positive/negative integer return value acceptable output?

Comment: @Rogem That's pushing it a bit but reading your write-up, that's fine. I did say output is quite flexible.

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 50 bytes

Takes input as a pointer to an interleaved list (i.e. `{them#1, us#1, them#2,...}`).

Returns one option via modification, and the other via return value.

Negative values indicate bottom of the inning, positive values indicate top of the inning. Zeroes are "empty". The absolute value of the output is the number of the inning. So, `-4,5` indicates the possibilities being top of the fifth and bottom of the fourth, and `1,0` indicates the only possibility being the top of the first.

The return value of the macro can be used to determine whether there's one or two possible innings; the return value is `0` if there's no other inning. Otherwise, it is the number of the inning.

Zero bytes of source code. Use the following as a preprocessor flag:

```c
-Df(o,n,l)=({o=n%2?~n/2:n/2+1;l[n-1]?-o-~n%2:0;})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZFBCoMwEEXXeoogCAmd0MRNi2Ld9BbWhUYUwcbSFroI8ehNs1MsUZAwgZnP@/NhBG2FMMbcy05igpTvdfKNSqgS3/O9Km1wCQwwttO8IEoTYoXH07YNDpRG9IJUWENY65sMwIKoIjOUTyhbsGwTPs9gmB6HP6uFutuYrxrzTeOIOSM7/vWNbmoryckRZG3dXtO1cziPoc1XNH3Zvgz9GHpt8AASepJiNaQyjLJRHqPY1oEnfS4pLzI60NEqMUs0@QE)

### Degolf

```c
-Df(o,n,l)=({
// Define a function-like macro f(o,n,l)
// o is the output variable, n is the size of the list, 
// l is a pointer to the first element of the list.
o=n%2?~n/2:n/2+1;
// If there's an odd number of elements, first possible inning is -(n+1)/2. 
// Else, it is (n/2)+1.
l[n-1]?-o-~n%2:0})
// If the score from the last inning is non-zero, the other possible inning
// needs to be determined; flip the sign of first output value then deduct 
// 1 from it if the number of elements is even.
```

Comment: Also, this could be golfed an additional 4 bytes if I can assume the list to be in reverse order (last to first), or the pointer to point to the last element in the array. Didn't go for that, as it felt like too much of a cheat.

Comment: I'd love to hear from @veskah if taking input as you did is ok, because it seems quite different (and useful) from the original spec.

Comment: @BLT By convention, interleaving is how lists of lists are done in C; multiple dereferencing is very taxing on resources. Other option would be to have one list after the other, but then it would be very impractical to append new elements to.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>52 48</s> 45 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to some restructuring from nwellnhof!*

```perl6
->\a,\b{(+a,a==b if (b,a)[a>b].tail;b+1,a>b)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJauYKvwX9cuJlEnJqlaQztRJ9HWNkkhM01BI0knUTM60S4pVq8kMTPHOknbUAfI06z9X5xYqZCuER2ro8ClAAbRsZrWXFBRAxzCOiBoiCQJETHAVINMxuqgKUeSNoRrVUAYj6I8Fk3eAEP@PwA)

Anonymous code block that takes input as two lists, top then bottom. Output is a list of tuples, where the first element is the inning number and the second element is True or False, corresponding to Bottom or Top.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
       {                                    }  # Anonymous code block
->\a,\b   # That takes input lists a and b
        (                                  )   # Return a list of
                                    b+1,a>b    # A list of 
                                               #  The length of the second list plus 1
                                               #  And top/bottom
         +a,a==b     # And the length of the first list
                     # And the other of top/bottom
                 if  # Only if:
                    (b,a)[a>b]      # The current of top/bottom's
                              .tail # Last element exists and is not 0
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>103</s> 96 bytes

```r
function(a,b,l=sum(a|1),k=sum(b|1))I(l,I(l-k,I(a[l],c(l,-l),-l),I(b[l],c(-l,l+1),l+1)),1)
I=`if`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYxNCoQwDEb3c5IEU2gO4ElEsC0UxKig42pmzt7pzyYuJCR5vI/kSCn28drCe943cORJ@vNawX0ZaanoM@JnmuMEQm2ZpYEbZKSQtRGsXa1v1ghJl7@UgcT4SxECYE4QXwWtZirFxTS0TwHfAz3VtQr44dNNW6XTHw)

*@digEmAll saved 7 bytes!*

Takes two <s>lists</s> vectors as input, and outputs one or two integers representing the possible innings. Positive integers are the top of the inning, and negative integers are the bottom of the inning.

In R, positive integers are truthy, so I can use the difference in lengths as the first argument to `if()`.

Comment: You'd probably have better luck with `[[` as an `if` replacement since you use `[` in your code.

Comment: @Giuseppe I tried it with `<` and `^`. I think `[` was the one used in the example I remember.

Comment: You can also give another name to `'if'` (and remove `{}` and move `f=` outside) : [96 bytes](https://tio.run/##dYzBCcMwDEXvmUSiMlgDeADPEAqxDYYQNYG2uXV3V04uyiEIfR7vI71bDa3ua/nO2wqJMkn47C9IP0ZaDsyKGEFI1y2aaZQnFRVO8NgI@VROSB562AOJcYhhmuvUKhRA7RGHjt4y9eFuTvR3BV8Lm@baFHzz6aK90e0P "R – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 75 bytes

```javascript
f=(a,c=1,p=0,z=0)=>1/(t=a[p][c-1])?f(a,c+p,1-p,t):[c,p]+(z?[,c+p-1,1-p]:'')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZFPS8MwGIfv@RSBHZa4t38CemmJg9704A7uFqILMd0qXRvaTGXiZ6/t1mmLkxEI5H2f5/eG5FW9qVpXmXVeUb6Ypkk5UaA5A8tD2POQ8lsWEMeVsFJoj0k6TztiZoF5FhyNhAYrZ2Q/F13VY11dRtMpbZypnVa1qTHHKzS5K@zORUgICRhhISVGk8XOdUXMlmgAhOeIZERAt9iROx7CEX6zvICzEX6dwHlluEv4HTbojJNY2EYxdmH8ePgS2gv8FcJ/hQStYrRVTm9M1T5u0JtEPE3kFT1x/TFYx@h9k@UGE9fCveabD6PJzxdRij8RxuIZcNZlAS4PIbI1XNx2dFnUZW78vFyTlNw/Lh58q6rakANO6UnwXZVtCaUx@mq@AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>135</s> <s>129</s> <s>126</s> <s>125</s> <s>123</s> 119 bytes

```python
a,b=input()
c=len(a)
e,f=`c+1`+"T",`c`+"B"
print((f+e,e)[b[-1]<1],(`c`+"T"+f,f)[a[-1]<1])[len(b)<c]if b else"1"+"TB"[c]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7BCoMwDIbvfYqSUzs7sLvsYi8@g7dQ0HYpE6STzcH29F0VmR4kkPx8Sf5k/E73R7wk/7gRNxwAUqec6eP4noRk3gwURScZqWBaX@i2gAZU63OtgY3PPk5ChIIUSXR41rbSVoml30ARVJDYrVji7OVk5W0fuOM0vAg05MEa0NuUbzP6kOfLLyd@TYhWobUMsfwLNUe@sarykOqZrnKft7Ud1wcOO9dyYz8)

-1 with thanks to @ovs

-4 thanks again to @ovs

Comment: `if d else"11BT"[c<1::2]` for -3

Comment: `if d` I can see (shouldn't have missed that!) but `else"11BT"[c<1::2]` doesn't come out any shorter for me unless I am missing something.

Comment: No worries @ovs as I found another way inspired by your `if d` anyway.

Comment: Instead of `if d` you can do `if b`, then you do not need to store `len(b)` in variable.

Comment: @ovs I looked at that but also need `d` for `[d<c]`. Can't see a way round that. Any ideas?

Comment: @ovs Ah got you. Very smart. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
ZẎṖṠṪ$Ð¡Ẉd2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/q4a6@hzunPdy54OHOVSqHJxxa@HBXR4rR/8PtRyc93Dnj///oaAMdEDREJmN1uBSg4sgyhrGxCgA)

First element: 0-based index of column.
Second element: `0` for top, `1` for bottom.

Output is a list of one or two pairs as specified above (prettified to show it better). The output innings are in reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 65 bytes

```python
a,b=input()
exec"a,b=[0]+b,a;print[len(b)][a[-1]<len(a+b)%2:];"*2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYxBCsMgEEX3nkKEQkwsqJtC05xkmIWmQgPFSLHQnt6qbYmLMDD8/5h54R1vq9dpXq@OTpQxloyw0@LDM3acuJebWQEgcbDCjOGx@Ah35zvLEQwcFV5KM4PlB33GkfU61SOSXfWfVndPTwkABSASyLZ/EGVUrt8kd6kq9Bfbvb01XO0YGqvc2Ac)

Prints two lines, first the bottom inning possibility then the top one, as a singleton list. If either one is not possible, that list is empty.

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), <s>84</s> 75 bytes

```
import StdEnv
$ =length
?v|last[0:v]>0= $v=0
@a b| $b< $a=(?a,$a)=($a+1,?b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY0xC8IwEIXn5lfckEExQrqKsQ46CG6OMcO1xlpIophYEfztxlQHqyAHx3vf495VRqOL9ri7GA0WGxcbezqeA2zCbulaQkEY7epwIEV7N@iD5JNWzbgA2gpO5gjlHWg5BYpiUCCjOBQDiqOcFeUwbgKmKgFyDuGgLVw8bLcgO82SUTAdQ9A@eEWuTfqRvUx3QLJMSsWkUuwleV@zbvJE3or/C/KfoL8/1z2e/2n6xvyDE1XxUe0N1j6OV@u4uDm0TeWf)

Defines the function `@ :: [Int] [Int] -> (Int, Int)` and some helpers.
Gives output in the form `(Top, Bottom)` where a zero signifies a null possibility.